# subtract operator on numpy.bool_

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

Unintentionally i made subtract operator on numpy.bool_ instead of python native bool. the result surprised me.

```
import numpy as np
np.False_ - np.True_
>> True
```

while native python bool type behavior looks much more reasonable for me.

```
False - True
>> -1
```

Why np.bool_ does not cast to int like native python types, when i try to operate subtract?

BTW, why numpy.float64(1.0) > 0 return numpy.True_ and not just True?

Comment: `bool(-1) == True`. That should give you a hint what's going on.

Comment: @DeepSpace so, you suggest that in numpy, when we call "-" operator on booleans, we actually do bool(int(false) - int(true)) ?

Comment: We actually subtract two `numpy.bool_` instances and the result is again a `numpy.bool_` instance. So it is equivalent to `numpy.bool_(bool(numpy.False_) - bool(numpy.True_))`. Sidenote: you should get a `DeprecationWarning` from executing your code snippet.